# Make "Greedy" Table Cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a row in a table that has 3 cells in it with values A, B, and C and the table is the full width of the screen, which is more than enough room for all 3. Right now, when they display, all cells are getting 1/3 of the room, but this isn't what I want. I want the 2nd and 3rd cells to be their "correct" size, and the first cell to take up the difference. I can't just set the width on them because they are dynamically sized. How can I do this?

Comment: you mean the three have their width set dinamically? or just B and C?, if you leave A without a width, it will do what you asked.

Comment: @jackJoe - B and C need to be the width over whatever their contents are. Whatever room is leftover, A should take.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried Diodeus and Rune's methods, but it didn't work for my example. I ended up doing a merge on cells B and C as I couldn't really find anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Downvote: 'I didn't find a solution' is not an accepted solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the width of the table to 100%, the width of A to 100% and B and C to auto.
Tested and working

```
<table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">A</td>
        <td width="auto">BB</td>
        <td width="auto">CCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: auto is the default width, so only the 100% width on the cell in question needs to be specified.  (Worked for me.)

Answer (score 2):

Code **A** and **C** in pixels and give **B** a width of 100%

Comment: Downvote: the pixel value will be ignored. This only works because you set width to 100% for one column. This will have the same result as Deep Frozen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rune's answer with Pistos' comment got me close.  The last step was to add style="white-space:nowrap" to the non-greedy columns, giving:

```
<table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">A wide column</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">Compact column 1</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">Another compact column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Works for me in Firefox 25.

Answer (score -2):

Try,

```
<table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100" style="background:#ff0000; display:block">A</td>
        <td width="100%" height="100" style="background:#00ff00; display:block">BB</td>
        <td width="100%" height="100" style="background:#ff00ff; display:block">CCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Downvote: Did you even test this? https://jsfiddle.net/35cebp4r/ Why should this work *at all*?